# How to allow Node.js child_process.execSync to run `scp -P 4422 root@myserver.com:/data/backups/...` without getting Permission Denied

Tags: node.js, scp

I am running a simply Node.js process to backup my data everyday by using `child_process.execSync` to run:

`scp -P 4422 root@myserver.com:/data/backups/dbs.zip /data/backups/dbs.zip`

Notice if I run the above command directly, it will work. But when I do it in Node, the log I got is:

```
[2020-03-04 05:00:00] error downloading backup...Command failed:

Permission denied, please try again.
root@myserver.com: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Do I have to create a key file for Node.js' child_process to use when it fires scp? If so, how come if I run `scp -i id_rsa.pem -P 4422 root@myserver.com:/data/backups/dbs.zip /data/backups/dbs.zip` in Node.js it just stuck (like it even stops running any async actions such as `appendFile`. It also created a lot of processes called `(node)` and these processes cannot be killed.

```
const path = require('path');

const {
  backupPath,
  downloadPath
} = require('../../conf');

const keyPath = path.join(
  __dirname,
  '../../key/id_rsa.pem'
);

const downloadProcess = log => {
  const { execSync } = require('child_process');
  log('downloading backup...');
  try {
    const date = new Date();
    const backupName = `db_${date.format('yyyy-MM-dd')}.tar.gz`;
    const command = `scp -i ${keyPath} -P 4422 root@myserver.com:${backupPath}/${backupName} ${downloadPath}/${backupName}`;
    log(`running command: ${command}`);
    const stdout = execSync(command);
    log(`downloaded backup ${backupName} at ${downloadPath}${'\n'}stdout:${'\n'}${stdout}`);
  } catch (e) {
    log(`error downloading backup...${e.message}`);
  }
}

module.exports = downloadProcess;
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet how you call this child_process.execSync with params?

I think it might be related to uid and gid. 
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Comment: @ Žilvinas Jocius I just did

Comment: Have a closer look at comparing uid and gid when you launch manually and using child_process.execSync. Leave an update about your progress.

Comment: @ŽilvinasJocius how do I do that?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333598/how-could-one-determine-uid-gid-of-running-process

Or simply console.log(execSync('id -u').toString()); and then with id -g. That way you will know your child process id. and then have a look at uid and gid when you launch process by yourself manually. Compare them. I assume by default it should be the same. But still worth a try.

Comment: @ŽilvinasJocius they are indeed the same